# I want to check a value in column A is also present in column B

Tags: python, pandas

Example data set below,

```
df1= ['A','B','C','D']
df2 = ['B','D','A','C']
```

how do i check if any value in df[1] match any value in df[2]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `isin`:

```
df[1].isin(df[2]).any()
```

Answer (score 0):

[intersection()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) might help, it will create a set containing all values ​​existing in both df1 and df2:

```
df1= ['A','B','C','D']
df2 = ['B','D','A','C']

output = set(df1).intersection(set(df2))
# output = {'D', 'A', 'B', 'C'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `in` keyword in python

```py
df1= ['A','B','C','D']
df2 = ['B','D','A','C']

print(df1[0] in df2) #prints True becuase df1[0] is in df2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge`:

```
print(df1.merge(df2, on='col1', how='inner'))
```